# Minimum PostgreSQL requirement to view all databases?

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

Long time MariaDB/MySQL DBA, two weeks into being a Postgres DBA and I'm stumped...

I am creating a script that scans a host and ennumerates the databases but I'm having difficulty nailing down the least-privilege Postgres permissions.  The script works fine when testing with SUPERUSER, but I'm not sure what permissions beyond USAGE it needs.  It seems that any combination I come up with isn't working.

Comment: Show us your script. How do you "scan a host"? Also what does "not working" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to get a list of databases in a PostgreSQL cluster is a database user that can connect to one of the databases. Then you can run the SQL statement

```
SELECT datname
FROM pg_database
WHERE datallowconn;
```

Comment: So that will allow the user to see all the databases in the instance, no matter if they have access to them or not?

Comment: Right. PostgreSQL shows all metadata to everyone (certain ones, like passwords, are restricted to superusers).